# How to calculate a breakdown of the chance of any number of successes where each instance has a difference chance of success?

Tags: probability

Example: I have a set of 2 die, a d3 and a d4. If I roll the set there are 12 possible outcomes.
For each die that rolls its max value I gain 1 point, there are 3 possible scores: 0, 1, or 2.

1,1 = 0

1,2 = 0

1,3 = 0

1,4 = 1

2,1 = 0

2,2 = 0

2,3 = 0

2,4 = 1

3,1 = 1

3,2 = 1

3,3 = 1

3,4 = 2

Breakdown:

Chance at 0 score = 6/12

Chance at 1 score = 5/12

Chance at 2 score = 1/12

How can I calculate a breakdown like this without writing it out manually? Say for a more complex set of die. In my case I have 3d3, 2d4, 1d6, 1d8, 1d10, 1d12, and 1d20, (yes this is for dnd), giving me a potential score of anywhere between 0 and 10. I need to figure out what the chances are for each individual score.

Comment: For score 1, Find out the combinations that only one dice is rolled maximum. It is the  value of numerator.